# Find symbolic link created for Sublime text 2 to replace with Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublime-text-2, sublime-text-3

I don't remember where I have setup this Sublime text 2 command line *symbolic link* and now I just upgraded to **Sublime Text 3** and I want to replace that *symbolic link* instead, but I can't find where I have point that.

How can I find an existing *symbolic link*? I named that `sub`

In sublime text 3 this is how you do it

```
ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" ~/bin/subl
```

Comment: Did you call "which sub"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ls -l $(which subl)
```

That will find the executable in your PATH and if it's a symlink what it is pointing to.

A more direct approach

```
readlink -e $(which subl)
```

Comment: That is exactly what I'm looking for!

Answer (score 0):

First, type

```
rm ~/bin/subl
```

to remove the old symlink. Then, enter

```
ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" ~/bin/subl
```

and the next time you run `subl` from the command line, Sublime Text 3 should start up.

Comment: I don't have anything inside `~/bin` at all and that folder isn't even exist.

Comment: Also my old _symbolic link_ named `sub`